# FFmpeg: What are the h264_vaapi and hevc_vaapi encoders? How do they work? Do they just use the Video Coding Engine / Encoding ASIC on AMD GPUs?

Tags: ffmpeg, video, nvidia-graphics-card, encoding, amd-graphics-card

The last part especially is what I'm wondering. How exactly does VAAPI work? Does it just use the the way that NVENC or `h264_amf` and `hevc_amf` works? Would it be possible to use the main GPU cores on either Nvidia or AMD cards?

From what I found from looking up the `h264_vaapi` and `hevc_vaapi` encoders, they're just the linux equivalents of `h264_amf` and `hevc_amf`, right?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: You may find a general overview in [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Video_Acceleration_API).